# How does this code print odd and even?

Tags: c

```
#define MACRO(num, str) {\
            printf("%d", num);\
            printf(" is");\
            printf(" %s number", str);\
            printf("\n");\
           }

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num & 1)
    {
        MACRO(num, "Odd");
    }
    else
    {
        MACRO(num, "Even");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain the above code (if/else condition and how it prints "Odd" and "Even")

Comment: In binary representation, odd number has least significant bit set, but even numbers don't because (frequency of 2). `& 1` tests this bit and take `Odd` path when bit is set and `even` otherwise. For `MACRO` it is simple text replacement, you can try with hand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In binary any numbers LSB (Least Significant Bit) is `set` or `1` means the number is `odd`, and LSB `0` means the number is `even`.

Lets take a look:

```
Decimal    binary
1            001  (odd)
2            010  (even) 
3            011  (odd)
4            100  (even)
5            101  (odd)
```

SO, the following line

```
num & 1
```

Will produce either `0` means `false` or `1` means `true`. For example, `num = 5`, hence:

```
  5 & 1 (decimal)
= 101 & 001 (binary)
= 001
= true (boolean)
```

and the `if (num & 1)` will go for `true` path

```
MACRO(num, "Odd");
```

then the `macro` will replace by the code block (say `num` by `5` and `str` by `Odd`).

The rest is up to you. Cheers.

Read [Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) and [Bitwise operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The determination of a number being "odd" or "even" is in the below logic block.

```
 if (num & 1)
 ...
 else
 ...
```

If a number is odd, it's [binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation) will have the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) set to 1. So, for a odd number

```
 if (num & 1)
```

will evaluate as TRUE.

Needless to mention, for an even number, the same expression will evaluate to FALSE.

<sup>[NOTE: the `&` here is [bitwise AND operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)]</sup>

Now, the `#define` being a [preprocessor MACRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion), the `MACRO` will get replaced by the code block of the MACRO definition, printing the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

`if (num & 1)` checks if the bit 0 of num is 1. Each number with a 1 at the LSB is odd, each numebr with a 0 as bit 0 is even.